# Wordpress - Dynamic url inside shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am creating a wordpress site with an embedded booking form.

Example:

I would like to create a dynamic tag which I can input into this shortcode. I want to simply track the URL of the page where the form was submitted on my site.

I tried to create a function using php found here https://www.prodjex.com/2017/07/worpdress-shortcode-current-url/

The result however was the field "Webpage" returned "[geturl]" as text instead of calling the function.

Is it possible to call this function within the shortcode? Or is there a different solution available?

Comment: What are you talking about here, when you say _'the field "Webpage"'_? Sounds as if you are using this in some custom field - the content of which probably doesn't get send through the usual output filters, that would get the content _parsed for_ any shortcodes it might contain.

Comment: Using javascript, this is a trivial task. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event